# make laravel api only accesible by logged users in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I m quite new to laravel and sanctum I made the authentification api and now I want to make my CRUD api only accessible for the logged users

how can I do this please ?

Comment: You need to protect your route https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#protecting-routes you can either add a guard as middleware, to your route file. Or you controllers constructor

Comment: oh thanks @DannyEbbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the Laravel built-in API system (`api_token`) ,Then you can simply make the middleware `auth:api`

for example:

**way 1:
in controller**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

**way 2:
in the route**

```
Route::get('route', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

### Edit 1:

for laravel 7 and `sanctum`
look at laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#protecting-routes

Answer (score 0):

In the route filr like this

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

You might find this walk trough easyer to follow..
https://dev.to/romanpaprotsky/vue-js-token-based-authentication-with-laravel-sanctum-3a84

Usualy you probably use a combination of route prefix and group.. so you can add many routes to a group... needing sanctum auth guard... and maybe prefixed by , for example /api/v1/

You might wanna take a look here for groups
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-middleware